# Unable to use type providers using file as a source in docker only

Tags: docker, f#, type-providers

I am running out of ideas so I wanted to ask for help - maybe someone already had an adventure with F#, TypeProviders and Docker. 
The issue is that I am not able to use type provider (json or csv) with file as source in docker only (if I run it in the let's say old fashioned way then it works as expected).

The code is extra short;

**Program.fs**

```
open FSharp.Data;

type Config = JsonProvider<"config.json">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let config = Config.GetSample()
    printfn "%s" config.Whataver
    0
```

**config.json**

```
{
  "Whataver": "Value to print"
}
```

**Dokerfile** (Visual studio auto-generated one)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsoleFsharp/ConsoleFsharp.fsproj", "ConsoleFsharp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ConsoleFsharp/ConsoleFsharp.fsproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ConsoleFsharp"
RUN dotnet build "ConsoleFsharp.fsproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ConsoleFsharp.fsproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleFsharp.dll"]
```

Old fashion way result:

[image]

running in docker (linux):

[image]

I've already tried to use the file as embedded resource with TypePovider Embedded Resource setting but this does not change the behaviour. I can even have them embedded and this still works when I run it without docker, It even works when published as self-contained app single file... (without docker of course) But docker refuses to cooporate in any configuration. Thanks guys for any help in advance!

P.S Yes I am sure that the cinfig.json file is in the docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have used `Config.GetSample()` which takes the path to the file you specified in provider constructor (in the angle brackets). Use instead:

```
open FSharp.Data

type Config = JsonProvider<"config.json">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    // ensure you have set the "Copy" property of config.json to "Copy Always"
    // specify here relative path to config.json, for example:
    let path = "./config.json"
    let config = Config.Load(path)
    printfn "%s" config.Whatever
    // prints "Value to print"
    0
```

Again, ensure you have set the "**Copy**" property of config.json to "**Copy Always**".

Comment: Don't tell me that this is that easy! It works. Tank you:) On the other hand the Config.Load(path) has the same path that specified in the JsonProvider but this works in docker indeed. WHY :D Do you have any clue?

Comment: @Jinx Hi! Looks like it takes the path to **config.json** specified in project file, I don't know why) you can find the answer in the github repo :)